# Django - Query values based on the result of an existing query

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have a query that matches some foreign key properties `buy_book__entity` and `sell_book__entity` to a parameter `company_group`. I need to further add onto this query to filter the results only on the results that match a predicate. Is this possible to do in one query?

```
return (Q(buy_book__entity__company_groups__alias__iexact=company_group) & \ 
        Q(sell_book__entity__company_groups__alias__iexact=company_group)) & \ 
        # I only want to run the below query on objects which 
        # the book entity types are internal from the above queries output
        (Q(buy_book__entity__primary_company_group__alias__iexact=Case(
            When(buy_book__entity__type=ENTITY.INTERNAL, then=Value(company_group)),
            default=Value(None))) | \
        Q(sell_book__entity__primary_company_group__alias__iexact=Case(
            When(sell_book__entity__type=ENTITY.INTERNAL, then=Value(company_group)),
            default=Value(None))))
```

I tried the above query utilizing `Case` and `When` but this doesn't exactly work because it will give the value as `None` to the `primary_company_group` whereas I need it not to query by that at all, almost like an ignore. Since `primary_company_group` is a nullable foreign key this skews my results heavily. Just FYI, I don't want to filter all `entity__type` to internal. Just the ones that are internal, I need to run the further query on those.

I come from a C# background so using Linq I would do something like this on the output of the first query:

```
alreadyFilteredList.Where(x =>
{
    if (x.BuyBook.Entity.Type == EntityType.Internal && 
        x.SellBook.Entity.Type == EntityType.Internal)
        return x.BuyBook.Entity.PrimaryCompanyGroup == companyGroup ||
               x.SellBook.Entity.PrimaryCompanyGroup == companyGroup;

    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this without using `Case` or `When`. I've added an additional conditional that requires that the type either `!=ENTITY.INTERNAL` or that it passes the final `primary_company` test.

The `~` operator negates the query.

```
return (
    Q(buy_book__entity__company_groups__alias__iexact=company_group) &
    Q(sell_book__entity__company_groups__alias__iexact=company_group) &
    (
        ~Q(buy_book__entity__type=ENTITY.INTERNAL) | 
        (
            Q(buy_book__entity__primary_company_group__alias__iexact=company_group) |
            Q(sell_book__entity__primary_company_group__alias__iexact=company_group)
        )
)
```

Comment: I just noticed this doesn't seem to check for `sell_book__entity__type=ENTITY.INTERNAL`. I'm assuming I just need to add something like `(~Q(buy_book__entity__type=ENTITY.INTERNAL) & ~Q(sell_book__entity__type=ENTITY.INTERNAL))` ?

Comment: That looks right. I'm not sure 100% what your business logic is supposed to look like, but you should be able to do it by chaining your queries like that.